# how use jquery setTime?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

What should I do if I click on the button to show the Div Tag loaded for 5 seconds and make it disappear?

```js
$(document).on("click", "#umr", function() {
  if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
    $(this).next().show();
  } else {
    $(this).next().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53693260/edit) then click the snippet editor [<>]` and produce a [mcve] - but first look at setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout` function [see](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) example

```js
function showTitle() {
     $("#showTitleDiv").show();
     
     setTimeout(function() {
         $("#showTitleDiv").hide();
     },5000);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" onclick="showTitle()" >click </button>

<div id="showTitleDiv" style="display:none">
         show title show for 5 second.....
</div>
```